# I tried to login an existing user in my webpage, but i'm getting 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django

This is my views.py
I've created user manually. Not by using django form.

```
    def login(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST['username'],
            password = request.POST['password']
 
            user = auth.authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if User is not  None:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return redirect('/')

            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Invalid Credentials!')
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html'
```

Comment: There is a comma at the end of the `username = ...` line, this wraps it in a singleton tuple.

Comment: Yea I removed it. Still don't work. However I switched to inbuilt authentication :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set up authentication using the built-in User object or a custom User model that is identical to the built-in, I highly recommend you use Django's built-in class views to handle your authentication (logging in and out).

It requires much less setting up in your project and is super simple once you get familiar with using class views (as you should use class views for most generic things such as list and detail views).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView